# Question on preprocessor directives

Tags: c#

If I use proprocessor directives to define which code an OS will run, like so:

```
     #if winXP // Compiling for Windows XP
    platformName = "Microsoft Windows XP";
    #elif win2000 // Compiling for Windows 2000
    platformName = "Microsoft Windows 2000";
    #elif win7 // Compiling for Windows 7
    platformName = "Microsoft Windows 7";
    #else // Unknown platform specified
    platformName = "Unknown";
```

How does the system pick up which OS is being used?

This is an example from the book Visual C# 2010 Recipes, where the author says that the platformName variable (declaration ommitted), wil equal the OS above.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '#if' and '#elif's (else-if) are not seen by the compiler but by the preprocessor and only one of those four 'platformName = ' lines is seen by the compiler. The one that is compiled is decided by the presence of none, one or more of these:

```
#define winXP
#define win2000
#define win7
```

or, by specifying "/D" on the compiler command line. You can define more than one, only the first match in the if/elif sequence will be compiled.

Why do this?

Well, the Win32 API has evolved over the years and newer versions of the API have features that earlier versions don't. Also, some API functions behave slightly differently depending on the OS version.

Answer (score 0):

Will it not just compare the version number implied by the version name given (winXP, win7 etc.) and compare with the version number of the current system?

Answer (score 0):

The values you're checking in the preprocessor (win7, winXP, win2000, etc.) have to likewise be defined somewhere by the preprocessor.

Either explicitly in the source files, via `#define winXP` (which probably wouldn't help you here), or through your build system (in MSBuild, for example, try `/p:DefineConstants=WinXP`). Note that in this case, you must recompile to enable/disable these values. This is statements such as `#if DEBUG` are made useful, by the way, by compiling in a configuration that sets the `DEBUG` constant.

If you want to know how to determine the OS at runtime, have a look at [`System.Environment.OSVersion`](http://www.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion(v=VS.100).aspx) and the [`System.PlatformID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a8hyw88(VS.90).aspx) enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

If I need to detect OS version, I would use [Environment.OSVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion(v=VS.100).aspx). Although it is runtime checking, I prefer to use the abstraction given ty .NET framework.